Problem with using speedtest-go using adb
I'm working on a project (I'm begginer) where I need to run the speedtest-go command on my Android device via Termux and then download the result to my PC using PowerShell and ADB. Here’s what I’m trying to achieve:
Start Termux on the non-rooted Android device (Samsung S24 Ultra).
Run the speedtest-go command within Termux and redirect the output to a file on the device.
Pull the result file from the Android device to my Windows PC using ADB.
I have the following setup:
PowerShell running on Windows.
ADB installed and configured.
Termux with speedtest-go installed on my Android device.
Here is a sample PowerShell script I've been working on:
Simply (not working powershell script)
`# Launch Termux
./adb shell monkey -p com.termux -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER 1
Start-Sleep -Seconds 10  # Wait for Termux to launch
Run the speedtest-go command and save the result to a file
./adb shell input text "speedtest-go > /sdcard/speedtest_result.txt" #The \ does not help
Start-Sleep -Seconds 10  # Wait for command input
./adb shell input keyevent 66  # Simulate Enter key press
Wait for the command to complete
Start-Sleep -Seconds 60
Pull the result file from the Android device to the PC
./adb pull /sdcard/speedtest_result.txt C:\Users\User\Desktop\platform-tools-latest-windows\platform-tools\Speedtest
Write-Output "File saved: C:\Users\User\Desktop\platform-tools-latest-windows\platform-tools\Speedtest"
Issues:
`
The adb shell input text command does not seem to correctly handle the redirection (>), and I am unsure how to correctly format the input command to achieve redirection in Termux.
I'm also unsure if there are better practices or more efficient ways to handle this process.
Also I faced problems with permissions (termux is using other user then adb shell).
Questions:
How can I correctly run the speedtest-go command in Termux and redirect the output to a file using ADB and PowerShell?
Are there improvements I can make to this script to ensure it works correctly? Or any easier way to measure DL UL TP on android phone and redirect output to Windows?
Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks in advance!
[Expectations]
Script should run Termux on android phone - correct
Script should start the speedtest-go - correct
Script should redirect output to .txt file - failed
Later the .txt should be pulled to Windows.
Typing the command manually in termux works fine, but can't pull it to windows - no permisions to accesss /data/data/com.termux/files/home from Windows (adb) 

I think some commands may be easier if you directly execute speedtest-go from adb shell instead of executing it from within termux (assuming that this command is a command-line tool that has no special requirements regarding used libraries). The /data/data/ directory and subdirectories are never accessible via adb on non-rooted devices.

How did you install speedtest-go? As @Robert me ruined, why termux instead of run it directly from adb shell?

@DiegoTorresMilano Karlitos is searching for "an easy way measure DL UL TP on android phones" and there is already a working adb environment (adb pull is used). And it seems to me that this should be executed in an automated way using a script. Just executing one adb command via adb shell is way easier to automate instead of starting termux, entering the command, saving the output to a file, executing adb pull...
